# auto sync two mysql tables with exception

Tags: php, mysql, cron, phpmyadmin

i have 2 sql tables of a script that i need to be sync to another, this can be done with php cron (this was my plan) exept from one row

Table 1        Table 2

row 1  <---->  Row 1

Row 2  <---->  row 2

row 3  no sync row 3

both databases on same server
and the same user has full rights for both

i am looking for a php code to do this via a cpanel cron

on an after thought would it be best to merge the two so both updates with new data?

the issue is that in the example above i am needing row 3 to not change on both databases

I am very noob so please be nice lol Thx in advance

Update *******

i should learn how to explain a bit better.

both the databases are control panels for sites, one of the tables rows has the system url in it, so if i share the database "site 2" links refers back to "site 1" this is a complex problem for me as i am very new to this.

what i need is to keep both databases upto date except that single row which in turn be different for both databases.

i have not tried anything just yet as i wouldn't know where to start :( lol

Comment: So to be clear, you're looking for a 1 way sync, where `Database 2` overrides `Database 1` all the time?  Never the other way around?

Comment: So what have you tried?  What are your actual criteria for determining which rows do not need to be synched?  When you say "synch" do you mean rows from one table or updated into the other (i.e. one table is authoritative), or are you talking about a conditional bi-directional sync?

Comment: Keep both databases or both tables? If databases - there are some replication features in new MySQL version. See help: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont have to use cron. MySQL in current version supports `TRIGGERS` and `EVENTS`.

You can use TRIGGER to copy data to another table. That copy (or any other operation) may be triggered by some event (like insert, update or delete in table). `TRIGGER` may run any query or any PL/SQL code.

Other option is an `EVENT`. This is something like internal task sheduler built in MySQL. It can also run queries, or any PL/SQL code, but it is triggered by system time (like Linux Cron). It has many advantages compared to cron.

PL/SQL is procedural SQL, with loops, variables and more.

If you think you are "noob" - i have cure for you. Read books about MySQL or if you are lazy - watch some tutorials ( http://thenewboston.org , http://phpacademy.org ).

Nobody here will write code for you. We can only fix a bug, give advice etc. :)

EDIT.

Example of EVENT:

```
-- this is comment in SQL language (line starts with --)
CREATE EVENT event_daily_copy_something
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 DAY
    COMMENT 'This text will appear in MySQL Workbench as description of event'
    DO
      BEGIN
        INSERT INTO your_db_name.target_table_name(id, field)
          SELECT id, something
            FROM your_db_name.source_table_name
            WHERE id = 3;
      END
```

Synchronization of tables is quite complicated. I think you need few operations in event.

1. Check for new rows and copy
2. Check for deleted rows and delete them in "copy" table
3. Check for changed rows (here trigger on source table would be very useful, because trigger "knows" what row is edited and you can access new field values in table 1 and use them to update table 2).

[One of MySQL tutorials - thenewboston@youtube.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KgiCxe-ZW8o&list=PL173650DBBF608622)

Comment: is there any script or tutorial available online for this?
i have been putting this off for long enough, im afrad i don't know enough to get this to work lol

Comment: thanks but is there a link you may share with info on the issue (or challenge) i have ?

Comment: @RickNash you need to get knowledge about MySQL fundamentals. Under these links you can find some MySQL tutorials. I suggest to start with The New Boston. I will add EVENT example to my answer in a minute.

Comment: @RickNash I dont know what you know. If you are really total MySQL noob - start with lesson 1 and dont forget to experiment and make some exercises. Ps. See link added to answer at the end.

Comment: thank you for your answer :) what i might do is pay and outsource this but take your advice regarding the tutorials i looked at a few and i want to learn this!. i cant be noob forever :) lol thx again

Comment: feel free to give me a quote for this work to be completed :)

Comment: If you will outsorce things like this - you will become businessman, not programmer! Learn and never give up! :)